# Wrong frame for view in tableView.tableHeaderView after a second rotation

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, rotation, uitraitcollection

I want to build a simple Swift 3 iOS 10 app with two different layouts according to size classes. When my `viewController` has a `traitCollection.verticalSizeClass` of type `.regular`, I want my `blueView` (a subclass of  `UIView`) to be the `tableView.tableHeaderView` with an height of `50`. When my `viewController` has a `traitCollection.verticalSizeClass` of type `.compact`, I want my `blueView` to be on the left (with an Auto layout width constraint of `240`) and my `tableView` to be on the right.

---

This is the code of my `UIViewController` instance:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView! {
        didSet {
            tableView.dataSource = self
            tableView.delegate = self
        }
    }
    @IBOutlet weak var blueView: UIView!

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        return tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)
    }

    override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()

        if self.traitCollection.verticalSizeClass == .regular {
            blueView.bounds = CGRect(x: tableView.frame.origin.x, y: tableView.frame.origin.y, width: tableView.bounds.width, height: 50)
            tableView.tableHeaderView = blueView
        } else {
            self.tableView.tableHeaderView = nil
        }
    }

}
```

The following screenshot shows the storyboard with scenes set in portrait mode:

[image]

The following screenshot shows the storyboard with scenes set in landscape mode:

[image]

The complete project can be found on this [Github repo](https://github.com/imanoupetit/Traits).

---

Everything works fine on launch: `blueView` is set as the `tableView.tableHeaderView` and has the correct height of `50`. If I rotate my device, everything is still working fine: `blueView` and the `tableView` have correct constraints.

However, if I rotate the device a second time, `blueView` disappear out of the controller's view and the `tableView` displays an empty `tableHeaderView`. What can I do to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrong Auto Layout constraints were responsible for my problem. I've managed to solve it by removing `blueView`'s `constraints` and by toggling `blueView`'s `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` property at each rotation.

Although I doubt this is the best way to solve this problem, the following code works and generates no Auto Layout constraints error logs.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView! {
        didSet {
            tableView.dataSource = self
            tableView.delegate = self
        }
    }
    @IBOutlet weak var blueView: UIView!

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        return tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)
    }

    override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()

        if self.traitCollection.verticalSizeClass == .regular {
            blueView.removeConstraints(blueView.constraints)
            //blueView.constraints.forEach({ $0.isActive = false }) also works
            blueView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true
            blueView.bounds = CGRect(x: tableView.frame.origin.x, y: tableView.frame.origin.y, width: tableView.bounds.width, height: 50)
            tableView.tableHeaderView = blueView
        } else {
            blueView.removeConstraints(blueView.constraints)
            //blueView.constraints.forEach({ $0.isActive = false }) also works
            blueView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            self.tableView.tableHeaderView = nil
        }
    }

}
```